# Minimum difference of the values in column Y where the column X value must be different from each other

Tags: mysql

I want to know the minimum difference of 2 values in building_num where the worker_num must be different from each other. For example check this table:

```
worker_num | building_num
39                 0
39                 2
39                 6
39                 7
39                 15
39                 21
39                 25
39                 27
39                 29
39                 30
39                 31
50                 0
50                 1
50                 3
50                 15
50                 16
50                 18
50                 19
50                 24
50                 25
50                 32
```

So The 2 closest compared numbers are 0(39) & 0(50) and 15(39) & 15(50) and 25(39) & 25(50). They are all the same values so the difference is 0. So it must output 0.

If these rows weren't in it, the closest numbers could be 2(39) & 1(50), which have a difference of 1. So then the output must be 1.

The SQL code must be so simple, but I couldn't find a source. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```sql
SELECT MIN(t1.building_num - t2.building_num)
FROM table t1
JOIN table t2 ON t1.worker_num != t2.worker_num 
             AND t1.building_num >= t2.building_num
```

Comment: Wow. I didn't know you can use joins on only one table.

Comment: @KPSingh We join 2 separate and independent copies of a table.